# Mimic Soul Knight control system using JS and Unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I am trying to imitate the control system in Soul Knight. If you are unfamiliar, whenever a player places their finger on the screen, the joystick appears underneath their finger, then if they drag their finger the joystick tracks to it. This way you dont have to be super precise and worry about putting your finger in the perfect place for the joystick.

[Controls graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjqB0.png)
End Goal:
In the attached graphic i show what i would like to happen. Pretend the circles outside of the grey circle are the point where the user is touching with their finger. When the touch point moves as shown, i want the white circle within the gray circle to move as shown, in a circular arc to the left. I want this functionality but also want the circle to be able to move to anywhere within the gray circle if the user is touching there. 
Movement system:
As is, the current system finds the position of the touch and finds the difference between that and the center circle in both the x and y axis, then it divides both of those numbers by 10, then adds both values to the x and y axis. This way, the circle moves directly towards the touch. 
Constraint system:
I am using if statements and the Pythagorean theorem to ask the question "If your hypotenuse WOULD be greater than the radius of the big circle, then dont move." This effectively stops the circle, but once it is stopped it never moves again.

Other algorithms that would work better? 
Any code-specific ideas?
Any content you can point me to that already works like the system i desire?

Context for the code- "base" is the grey circle
Trackme is a public var I set to tell the white circle what object to move towards.

```
#pragma strict

private var itemPos:Vector3;
private var basePos:Vector3;
private var moveCount = 0;
private var seed = 1;
private var xdif = 0.0f;
private var ydif = 0.0f;

private var xdifbase = 0.0f;
private var ydifbase = 0.0f;
private var radiuscircle = 13;
private var parental : GameObject;
private var base : GameObject;
var trackme : String;


function Update () {

    parental = GameObject.Find(trackme);
    base = GameObject.Find("joystickbase");
    itemPos = parental.transform.position;   
    basePos = base.transform.position;   
    xdif = Mathf.Abs(itemPos[0] - transform.position[0])/10.0f;
    ydif = Mathf.Abs(itemPos[1] - transform.position[1])/10.0f;
    xdifbase = basePos[0] - transform.position[0];
    ydifbase = basePos[1] - transform.position[1];


    if (transform.position[0] < itemPos[0] )
    {   
        if (Mathf.Sqrt((xdifbase+xdif)*(xdifbase+xdif)  + ydifbase * ydifbase) < radiuscircle)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3(transform.position[0] +xdif, transform.position[1], transform.position[2]);
        }


    }

    if (transform.position[0] > itemPos[0] )
    {   
        if (Mathf.Sqrt((xdifbase-xdif)*(xdifbase-xdif)  + ydifbase * ydifbase) < radiuscircle)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3(transform.position[0] -xdif, transform.position[1], transform.position[2]);    
        }

    }

    if (transform.position[1] < itemPos[1] )
    {   
        if (Mathf.Sqrt(xdifbase * xdifbase  + (ydifbase+ydif)*(ydifbase+ydif)) < radiuscircle)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3(transform.position[0] , transform.position[1] +ydif, transform.position[2]);
        }           
    }

    if (transform.position[1] > itemPos[1] )
    {   
        if (Mathf.Sqrt(xdifbase * xdifbase  + (ydifbase-ydif)*(ydifbase-ydif)) < radiuscircle)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3(transform.position[0] , transform.position[1] -ydif, transform.position[2]);   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of checking _if_ the hypotenuse is greater, you would probably be better off moving the circle no matter what, and [Clamping](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) the max distance from the center of the gray circle.

Comment: That sounds like an awesome idea! So, i take away the if statements for the hypotenuse, leave the movement statements and then somewhere in the code i place clamp statement that limits the distance of the circle from the grey circle. 
So what would the code to do that look like? I followed the link you sent but I'm not sure what clamping the hypotenuse would look like. This would restrain it to a square....

    transform.position = Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, 
    0,20),Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, 0,20), 0);

But how to do it to the hypotenuse to make it a cricle?

Comment: One way would be to normalize the original position vector (Vector2.normalized), apply a multiplier (looks like *10 in your case), and clamp the multiplied value. then assign the transform.position using those clamped values.

Comment: It is working now @ryeMoss I want to upvote you for your help or say this questions is answered, how do i do that?

Comment: glad to hear it! I will turn my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to instead use [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) on the transform's position to clamp it within the bounds of your circle. You could accomplish this by first [normalizing](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html) the touch position from the center location of the circle, then multiply by your scalar, and clamp this value within your circle's bounds. You would then set your `transform.position` to the clamped values of this new vector. For example:

```
Vector2 normedVec = touch.position.normalized * 10;
transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(normedVec.x, -20, 20), Mathf.Clamp(normedVec.y, -20, 20);
```